# What is the difference between expected cost and average cost of an algorithm?

Tags: terminology, algorithm-analysis, average-case

While going through probabilistic/average analysis of an algorithm, I found written somewhere that average cost and expected cost are same. Can anyone please tell me what does exactly expected cost stands for.I think we take care of likelihood of an event while finding expected cost unlike average cost.

Comment: You should give a more specific example, but generally there is a difference between the expected running time, with respect to random choices not depending on the input, of a randomized algorithm on a worst-case input and the expected running time of a deterministic algorithm on a randomly-chosen input.  The latter is usually called "average case analysis".

Answer (score 4):

In short, the average is the expected value of the uniform distribution.

If $T(x)$ denotes the runtime of some algorithm on input $x \in \mathcal{X}$, then the *expected* runtime for input size $n$ is

$\qquad\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[T(X) \mid |X| = n] = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}_n} \operatorname{Pr}[X=x \mid |X| = n] \cdot T(x)$

given some random distribution for random variable $X$.

*Average* runtime is more specific and corresponds to

$\qquad\displaystyle \overline{T}(n) = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{X}_n|} \cdot \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}_n} T(x)$

or, in other words, the expected runtime given a uniform distribution over inputs of the same size.

Since we *usually* use the uniform distribution the terms are often used interchangeably in algorithm analysis.

One famous exception is the analysis of binary search trees. As opposed to averaging height over all rooted binary trees, we calculate the expected height w.r.t. the uniform distribution of different insert sequences ("random permutation model"), which assigns some (shapes of) trees a higher probability than others. That is not a technical detail: the average height of rooted binary trees is in $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ whereas the expected height of BSTs in the random permutation model is in $\Theta(\log n)$.

Comment: This assumes that the only source of randomness is in the input. The algorithm might be random too. Then you can talk about the expected runtime of the algorithm on one given input, or about the expected runtime of the algorithm given some random distribution of the inputs.

Comment: @Stef True. The principles carry over: you can talk about average case (weighted sum over all computations) and expected case (potentially different probabilities per computation).

Answer (score 1):

In statistics, the average is often used as an *estimator* for the expected value of a random variables. It is a reasonable choice because this way of estimating the expectation of a random variable whose distribution is unknown, is unbiased and converges to the true value of the expectation. Perhaps that's the motivation to treat both as being the same.

Note: The expectation (or expected value) of a random variable $x$ is usually defined as follows: Let $X$ be the set of all possible values for $x$ and $p(x)$ be its density function. Then 
$$
E[x] := \sum_X x\cdot p(x)
$$

is the expectation of $x$. Change the sum to an integral if $X$ is uncountable, (e.g. if $X = \mathbb{R}$)
If you don't know $p(x)$ you can apply Laplace's Principle of Insufficient Reason and assume each value of $x$ to be equally likely, i.e. $p(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ where $n=|X|$. Substitute into the above formula for the expectation and you have the formula for (arithmetic) average.

Answer (score 0):

If you are studying a Randomized algorithm, then expected cost or expected time complexity is a natural metric to analyze the cost or complexity of the algorithm. To understand this concept you need a brief background of Probability theory (concepts like Random variable, Expectation etc.).

By **expected cost** it means that what is the value of the cost in expectation. Generally the cost is represented as a **random variable** and then its **expectation** is computed to find the expected cost. And, surprisingly for any input of the algorithm the expected cost is same.

On the other hand, the average cost is computed for a deterministic algorithm by taking the average of the costs over all the inputs.

P.S: These concepts could be described in a clearer way in the context of specific algorithms. Thus it's better to provide more information like which algorithm you are studying.

Answer (score -2):

Strictly speaking, *expectation* is a property of a probability distribution whereas an average is a simple function computed from a set of numbers (typically, their mean).

However, in typical CS language, these terms are often confused. The "average running time" can either refer to the expected runtime when considering a random input, or in the case of randomized algorithms, it could mean the expected runtime given a specific input. In the latter case, the expectation is computed over all possible coin flips that the algorithm tosses.